# Is there an efficient algorithm to determine when a system of linear Diophantine equations has a positive solution?

Tags: combinatorics, linear-diophantine-equations

Let $A$ be a matrix with integer coefficients and let $\vec c$ be a vector of integers. Is there an efficient algorithm to determine if $A\vec x=\vec c$ has a solution $\vec x$ consisting of nonnegative integers? If so, can the algorithm be improved if the entries of $A$ and $\vec c$ are nonnegative?

My motivation is to determine whether certain monomials in the ring $\Bbb C[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ graded by the matrix $A$ exist.

Comment: This is the **integer programming** problem. One can relax the integrality constraints, solve the linear program (LP) with an arbitrary objective function, and hope one finds an integer solution. If the LP is infeasible, one can immediately conclude that there's no integer solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... forgot about the non-negative.

Assuming $A$ is not already square and symmetric, try 
$$ A^T A x = A^T c.  $$
At this point, $A^T A$ is symmetric positive semi-definite. If it is also positive definite, you can then ask whether $A^T c$ is in the integer lattice defined by $A^TA.$ Given all the attention to lattice reduction algorithms such as LLL, I would guess there are very good lattice membership algorithms available; I will see what I can find. If not, this is still a finite check and is easy enough for small $n.$

http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring13/CSCI-GA.3033-013/lectures/lecture-2.pdf

recommends A. Schrijver
*Theory of Linear and Integer Programming*